# Check multiple rows for a unique combination across a whole table

Tags: excel, dax, excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2016 and try to filter a simple table based on values across all rows and columns.
Let's assume the following table:

| ID | Customer | Work |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nancy | Inspection |
| 2 | Peter | Inspection |
| 3 | Peter | Inspection |
| 4 | Anna | Inspection |
| 5 | Nancy | Tire Change |
| 6 | Anna | Inspection |
| 7 | Tom | Tire Change |
| 8 | Anna | Tire Change |
| 9 | Anna | Tire Change |

I want to know only the customers, that had **only** an inspection. As soon as they had a tire change in addition to an inspection or only a tire change (like Tom), they should be filtered out.

So the result should look like this:

| ID | Customer | Work |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Peter | Inspection |
| 3 | Peter | Inspection |

Peter is the only one left, because across all rows he **only** had an inspection and nothing else.

I tried multiple ways for filtering duplicates and different logics, but it seems it won't be solvable without a vlookup or similar, to which I'm not used to.

Comment: So set criteria of "= Inspection" and "<> Tire change"

Comment: @SolarMike that seems correct, but how can I pack that into a formula, to check each row against the rest of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this works:

[image]

In cell F2;

```
=UNIQUE($B$2:$B$10)
```

In cell G2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,F2,$C$2:$C$10,"Inspection")-COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10,F2,$C$2:$C$10,"Tire Change")>=1,1,"")
```

In cell A15:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MATCH(B15,$G$2:$G$5,0)),"")
```

In cell B15:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE($G$2:$G$5,1),"")
```

So edit it as you wish. You can add another index() with match() to get the ID...

Deconstructing the formulae will help you understand how it works.

Comment: Wenn du mir eine Nachricht hinterlassen möchtest, auf welchem Wege ich dir einen Kaffee ausgeben kann, melde dich gerne. Danke dir tausendfach!

Comment: @SHA-256 sorry, I can do English or French...

Comment: Sorry, I thought your Swiss location meant you understand German, my mistake. 
If you leave me a message, about how I can spend you a coffee, message me. 
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @SHA-256 No worries, just the points system on here is good enough. Glad it helps though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one formula (pr column) if you have excel 365 (insider not needed):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(COUNTIFS($B2:$B10,$B2:$B10,$C2:$C10,"<>Inspection")=0,A2:A10,""))&"</s></t>","//s")
```

this formula is for column A and can be dragged to the right for the other columns

[image]

Comment: Be even better if you did not show duplicates...

Comment: There are duplicates in the requested result by OP

Comment: You could alter the filterxml to remove duplicates (change `//s` with `//s[not(preceding::*=.)]` if you only need the names column: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(COUNTIFS($B2:$B10,$B2:$B10,$C2:$C10,"<>Inspection")=0,B2:B10,""))&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")`